# Swift SearchVC navbar

Tags: ios, swift, search

I am having trouble with the absolute LAST piece of my app , everything else is finished and functional. I used Ray Wunderlich tutorial to help me get this search feature working but I am stuck. The page loads and I can type usernames, but no results show up. The search is its own VC, which I Get through via tab bar. My aim is to search for users on my app by username for example "Kobe Bryant". The main home page shows all my users' posts. Not sure why no results are coming up any tips would be great. Much appreciated. This is my code for the search VC.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var users = [PFUser]()
var filteredUsers = [PFUser]()
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    // Setup the Search Controller
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Users"
    definesPresentationContext = true

    fetchUsers()
}

// MARK: - Private instance methods

func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
    // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
    return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
}

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredUsers = users.filter({( user : PFUser) -> Bool in
        return (user.username?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    })
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func fetchUsers() {
    let userQuery = PFUser.query()
    userQuery?.includeKey("username")
    userQuery?.findObjectsInBackground{ (objects: [PFObject]?, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        guard let objects = objects as? [PFUser] else { return }
        self.users = objects
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func isFiltering() -> Bool {
    return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FollowingCell", for: indexPath) as! FollowingTableViewCell
    let user: PFUser
    if isFiltering() {
        user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        user = users[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.usernameLabel?.text = user.username
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isFiltering() {
        return filteredUsers.count
    }


    return users.count
}


}

extension SearchViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    // MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

Comment: `filterContentForSearchText` is invoked? `filteredUsers` in the method has objects?

Comment: Have you added break points to see if things are running like @Ryan asked?

Comment: @Ryan I am not sure this is what I'm confused about on the tutorial. I was under the impression that the method , using users.filter , was populating filteredUsers. And that thew filteredContentForSearchText , was being invoked in the extension in updatesearchresults function